# Resultado de multiplicação e divisão com duas casas depois da vírgula

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá pessoal tudo bem?

Estou fazendo uma atividade para meu curso de python, é um script que basicamente calcula a área de uma parede em metros e diz quantos litros vão ser usados de tinta.
O problema é que quando digito um valor muito alto de altura e largura, tipo, 543.404 x 456.435 o script me retorna o seguinte resultado de área 2.3e+05, eu queria que todos os resultados viessem com pontos flutuantes e apenas duas casas depois da vírgula, segue meu código.
Obs: no meu programa 1 litro de tinta pinta 2m2 de área, por isso a variável t = 2.

Obs2: Alguém me ajuda a postar o código de forma correta aqui no site.

```
print('Bem vindo ao programa de orçamento\nde tintas: ')

l = float(input('Digite a largura da parede em metros: '))

print('Muito bem!')

a = float(input('Agora digite a altura da parede: '))

m = (l * a)

print ('Certo! Você tem uma área de: {:.2} metros' .format (l * a))

t = 2

print ('Para pintar esta parede, você vai\nprecisar de: {:.2} litros de tinta!'.format(m / t))
```

Comment: Olá! Pode postar código que permita a reprodução do problema?

Comment: editei aqui amigo

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque por padrão, quanto printando floats assim, o Python tenta usar notação científica pra encurtar o resultado.

Você pode forçar ele a te dar o resultado por extenso usando `{:.2f}` ao invés de só `{:.2}`:

```
print('Certo! Você tem uma área de: {:.2f} metros'.format (l * a))
t = 2
print('Para pintar esta parede, você vai\nprecisar de: {:.2f} litros de tinta!'.format(m / t))
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função round para arredondar os valores, então mostrar os valores corretamente com a função print. Os caracteres que aparecem são os valores em notação científica.

```
print('Bem vindo ao programa de orçamento\nde tintas: ')

l = float(input('Digite a largura da parede em metros: '))

print('Muito bem!')

a = float(input('Agora digite a altura da parede: '))

m = round((l * a),2)

print ('Certo! Você tem uma área de: ',m,'metros')

t = 2
litros =round( (m/t) , 2)

print ('Para pintar esta parede, você vai\nprecisar de: ',litros,' litros de tinta!')
```

Comment: e para postar o código aqui de forma correta, como faço?

Comment: Seleciona o teu código e aperta na aba superior nas chaves ( {} )

Comment: @LeandroSargi ou instala minha extensão ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/addon/stack-overflow-indentation/) ou [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-overflow-and-stack/enmhejgjihfndjijalimdgiiielefgfo)), seleciona o texto e aperta Tab :)

Comment: eu não entendi essa questão das chaves, é que uso o celular para postar as coisas aqui, e o código sempre sai como texto, aí alguém sempre revisa, eu quero postar direto.

Comment: Pois é, não sei como fica no celular. Nunca usei! Escolhe alguma resposta correta!